# RCE in CVE-2023-418925: Can it be exploited without being logged into Craft?

Tags: security

Does anyone know if the RCE vulnerability in CVE-2023-418925 ([Github link](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/security/advisories/GHSA-4w8r-3xrw-v25g)) can be exploited without being logged into Craft? I have a couple of smaller sites that I'd rather not update right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be exploited whether you're logged in or not.

You can find more info at the following links:

- https://putyourlightson.com/articles/critical-craft-cms-security-vulnerability
- https://github.com/craftcms/cms/security/advisories/GHSA-4w8r-3xrw-v25g

Comment: Hi Jalen, thank you so much for your answer! It really helped me out. I appreciate your time and expertise.

Comment: @Magnus sure thing, my pleasure 